# Get build specifications list and other Properties

Tags: labview

I am facing some challenge to read Project's build specification list and some properties of build specs (Ex. Destination Path).

Is there a good way to do this, VI scripting?

Please have a look on picture below: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use some internal VIs from Application Builder, I believe you can accomplish your goal.

I used my VIKit tool [VIQueryBuildSpecs](https://github.com/wireddown/VIKit) as a starting point to show how:

[image: VIQueryBuildSpecs.vi]

The internal Application Builder VIs are located here: `vi.lib\AppBuilder\AB_API\Build`:

- Open Build.vi
- Get Primary Destination Path.vi
- Close.vi

While this works for most output target types, the only way I see to get this information for a zip file target is using `Preview.vi` instead of `Get Primary Destination Path.vi`, but it takes much longer since a preview is generated.

Comment: Sure this will help, Thanks a lot.